# Python - operator overloading in vector math

Tags: python

Code:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0.0
        self.y = 0.0

    def __mul__(self, scalar):
        v = Vector()
        v.x = self.x * scalar
        v.y = self.y * scalar
        return v    


v = Vector()
v.x = 2
v.y = 5
v = v * 2
```

Question: is there a way to overload mul operator in a way that this becomes possible:

```
v = 2 * v
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`__rmul__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmul__):

```
def __rmul__(self, scalar):  # self: right operand (Vector)
    v = Vector()
    v.x = self.x * scalar
    v.y = self.y * scalar
    return v
```

`__rmul__` called when the left-hand operand does not support the corresponding operation (`__mul__`).

Comment: I haven't found that here https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html but have here https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: @maxest, Did you click the link in the answer? (The link is on the `__rmul__` in the first line). BTW, I didn't mention about `operator` module.

Comment: Oh, it seems I have missed the link you provided. Thanks again :)